# Tax Refund from Germany on Student Visa

Tags: schengen, germany

I have searched this but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
I am an exchange student in Germany and go back home almost every month. I am non-EU so I am here on a Student Visa. Is it possible to get tax refund for the items I have purchased here?

Comment: Flagged for migration to Expats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The official web page](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Tax-free-shopping/tax-free-shopping_node.html) explains the process quite clearly.

Your nationality seems to be irrelevant. **What is important, however, is whether you have a *residence permit* or not**. You should have already applied for it if you are staying in Germany for longer than 3 months. **Without having a residence permit, VAT refunds are possible if you can prove that your place of residence is outside the EU, but if you have a residence permit for Germany, the you cannot get a tax refund**. There are many conditions connected to a VAT tax refund, and you will need to check with the vendor before the sale that you will be issued the necessary documentation.

Comment: Where does it say that the applicant cannot be an EU national? It says that nationality is irrelevant, that place of residence is all that matters.